# Create a PDF file from an SVG with Python

Tags: python, svg, reportlab

I have a svg document which I want to convert into a PDF document. I have already done this.

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

drawing = svg2rlg(inputFileName)
renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, outputFileName +".pdf")
```

Now the problem is that on the one hand, when I look at the PDF, the PDf document is much larger than my actual drawing.But I want the PDF page to be completely filled in with my drawing and not with white color. Does anyone know how to adapt an SVG file to a PDF page?

On the other hand, the font that still exists in the SVG file simply disappears.The writing is simply gone.

Does anyone know why this disappears? Is it related to my conversion and the associated Python library?
Does anyone know of another way to create PDFs from SVG files?

[PDF Image section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo8pj.png)

[SVG Image section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L5gh.png)

Comment: I am happy about every little help as I have absolutely no idea how this error occurs: /

Comment: On the PyPi page (https://pypi.org/project/svglib/) it states as one of its features that "install a Python command-line script named svg2pdf". Maybe you can bypass the reportlib and try that command? Note: I have no experience with either but I'm just trying to come up with a solution.